# for loop does not run till the end index of the list

Tags: python

Below code runs for two times only. No idea why it is happening.

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
count=0
for letter in a:
    print(letter)
    b=a.pop()

    count+=1
print("total loop count is "+str(count))
```

I expect that the loop should run for four times.
If I comment / remove line `b=a.pop()`, then the loop runs for four times.

I expect print for the count after the program exit loop should be four, but actual output print for the count is 2.

Comment: Do you know `pop()` also removes element from the list?

Comment: After `pop()`ping two times, the length of the list is reduced to `2`

Comment: Never change the length of the list your looping over in the same step (with `pop`/`push`).

Answer (score 7):

The `list.pop()` method without a parameter removes the last item of the list. Check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html).

So basically what happens is:

- Loop 1 (letter is 1, 4 is removed)
- Loop 2 (letter is 2, 3 is removed)
- No loop 3 since the list a has no more elements.

Generally it is considered bad practice to modify a collection when iterating on its elements. Doing so often results in unintended behavior.

Answer (score 2):

1st step:
print the first element, remove the 4th one

2nd step:
print the second element, removes the 3rd one

... no elements left to print.

Answer (score 0):

Because you change the element size of the iterator `a` using the line:

`b=a.pop()`

every time running the line, the list `a` will remove its last element and the size of it will be reduced by 1.

the simplest way to get your expection is to make the iterator unchangeable at line 3 `for letter in a[:]`:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
count=0
for letter in a[:]:
    print(letter)
    b=a.pop()

    count+=1
print("total loop count is "+str(count))
```

and the output will be correct:

```
1
2
3
4
total loop count is 4
```

Answer (score 0):

a little improved code

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
count=0
while len(a)>0:
    count+=1
    print(a[-1])
    a.pop()

print("total loop count is {}".format(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand the concept. Use *enumerate()* to know the count of the iteration, When the pop is called for the second time the *len(a)* becomes 2(which means there is no 3rd item to print for the third iteration).
run below code once to get a better idea. It is sot recommended to pop or remove from the list inside for loop.

```
count=0
for iteration_count,letter in enumerate(a):
    print("Index Value:",iteration_count)
    b=a.pop()
    print("Length of a:",len(a))
    count+=1
print("total loop count is "+str(count))
```

While the below code would help you if you want to pop all the items.

```
count=0
while a:
    a.pop()
    print(a)
```